# How do Starweirds survive the vacuum of space and enter ships in hyperspace?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I was looking up strange Star Wars creatures and came across Starweirds. All the info I have been able to appear in hyperspace or in the vacuum of space (specifically Deep Space). They seem to be resistant to all non-force based attacks. I couldn’t find anything else about them. Is there an In-Universe reason as to how they appear/survive?

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Starweird

Comment: @Valorum, I looked there all ready. They don’t explain anything about this, it simply says that they appear.